# Как вернуть страницу после исполнения js скрипта?

Tags: c#

Есть на странице 3 вкладки. При переключении этих вкладок на странице генерируются ссылки javascript'ом(ajax запрос).

Я переключаю вкладку с помощью button(для отладки). В встроенном webbrowser она переключается.

```
public void goto_new_tab()
    {
        wait();
        foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
        {
            if (he.GetAttribute("id").Equals("tabRecentSellListings"))
            {
                he.InvokeMember("click");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Wait дает странице полностью загрузиться.

```
public void wait()
    {
        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```

И пытаюсь спарсить загруженные ссылки

```
public void getlinks()
    {
        wait();
        foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
        {
            if (he.GetAttribute("class").Equals("market_listing_item_name_link"))
            {       
                string currentHref = he.GetAttribute("href");
                console.AppendText(currentHref + "\n");
            }
        } 
    }
```

Но у меня возвращается начальная страница с дефолтной вкладкой.
Если начинаю смотреть в хроме код элемента, то все тэги и ссылки там присутствуют.
Как сделать так чтобы возвращался документ, уже обработанный javascript'ом?
На форме использую элемент WebBrowser (IE 11) для отображения страницы.
Вот кода подгруженного элемента (их 10). В данном случае мне нужна ссылка http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Genuine%20Bajie%20the%20Silken%20Swineling

```
<div class="market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row listing_719810587565497923" id="listing_sell_new_719810587565497923">

<div class="market_listing_item_img_container">     <img id="listing_sell_new_719810587565497923_image" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/W_I_5GLm4wPcv9jJQ7z7tz_l_0sEIYUhRfbF4arNQkgGQGKd3kMuVpMgCwRZrhyFY1OZ0v4CaOLQCwsGCpH4CUa8PqSI-VmoXIIJL4QwbjtBjNi70h1HUSHUDbdCDdV4ucuXgAPoDwWQeDFrw9hTgfGdhdiUBfEtC-OGYw/62fx62f" srcset="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/W_I_5GLm4wPcv9jJQ7z7tz_l_0sEIYUhRfbF4arNQkgGQGKd3kMuVpMgCwRZrhyFY1OZ0v4CaOLQCwsGCpH4CUa8PqSI-VmoXIIJL4QwbjtBjNi70h1HUSHUDbdCDdV4ucuXgAPoDwWQeDFrw9hTgfGdhdiUBfEtC-OGYw/62fx62f 1x, http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/W_I_5GLm4wPcv9jJQ7z7tz_l_0sEIYUhRfbF4arNQkgGQGKd3kMuVpMgCwRZrhyFY1OZ0v4CaOLQCwsGCpH4CUa8PqSI-VmoXIIJL4QwbjtBjNi70h1HUSHUDbdCDdV4ucuXgAPoDwWQeDFrw9hTgfGdhdiUBfEtC-OGYw/62fx62fdpx2x 2x" "="" style="border-color: #4D7455;" class="market_listing_item_img economy_item_hoverable" alt=""> </div>
    <div class="market_listing_price_listings_block">
                <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_action_buttons">
                                <div class="market_listing_buy_button">
                                                <a href="javascript:BuyMarketListing('listing_sell_new', '719810587565497923', 570, '2', '7307699798')" class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_small">
                            <span>
                                Buy Now                             </span>
                        </a>
                                        </div>
                        </div>
            <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price">
        <span class="market_table_value">
                                                    <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">
                    9,09 pуб.                   </span>
                <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_publisher_fee_only">
                    8,70 pуб.                   </span>
                <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_without_fee">
                    7,91 pуб.                   </span>
                            <br>
                        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_seller">
    <span class="market_listing_owner_avatar">
        <span class="playerAvatar in-game">
            <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d5/d55da399274862dcfad977b272f9582ce7ea5517.jpg" alt="">
        </span>
    </span>
</div>

    <div class="market_listing_item_name_block">
    <span id="listing_sell_new_719810587565497923_name" class="market_listing_item_name economy_item_hoverable" style="color: #4D7455;"><a class="market_listing_item_name_link" href="http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Genuine%20Bajie%20the%20Silken%20Swineling">Genuine Bajie the Silken Swineling</a></span>
    <br>
    <span class="market_listing_game_name">Dota 2</span>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: объясните кто-нибудь, что есть "вкладки"? "Закладка" - знаю, "кирпичная кладка" - знаю, "вкладки" - не знаю. А я всех великих полководцев знаю.

Comment: @Igor вкладки которые меняют содержимое страницы

Comment: Ага, это такой способ объяснения - не что это такое, а что это делает.

Comment: @Igor, вероятно это `tab`

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon, добавьте в вопрос больше подробностей: что это, например, WinForms, можно в теги добавить. Больше кода. Больше html разметки

Comment: Сколько времени проходит между `he.InvokeMember("click");` и `console.AppendText(webBrowser1.DocumentText);`?

Comment: @Igor я не знаю, но я пробовал ставить Thread.Sleep() на разное время, и результат не менялся

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon, так можете предоставить больше информации, кода и разметки?

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon, Это в итоге WinForms?

Comment: @Grundy Через просмотр кода элемента можно вернуть xpath  //*[@id="listing_sell_new_719810587565497923"]. Я в правильном направлении копаю?

Comment: @Grundy Да, это winforms

Comment: итак, вы загружаете в `webBrowser1` ссылку _http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Genuine%20Bajie%20the%20Silken%20Swineling_?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32166/discussion-between-grundy-and-thedarksideofthemoon).

Answer (score 1):

Частично разобрался. Через хром отследил xhr get запрос, который обновляет ссылки во вкладках при нажатии на них. В ответ приходит документ, который содержит нужные мне ссылки. Остается распарсить его.